# Giving a Title a Gilded Effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, color, titles, pstricks

Consider the code which compiles with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}

% Overlay Title
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \Huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{gold}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.35pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.09,-5.09)(5.09,12.09)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{gold}%
\psframe[fillcolor=darkgreen!95!black,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=darkgreen!95!black,linewidth=4pt](-5.09,-5.09)(5.09,12.09)% 

%top and bottom center
\rput[tl](-2.2,12){\psvectorian[width=4.3cm,flip]{71}}
\rput[bl](-2.2,-5){\psvectorian[width=4.3cm]{71}}

%four corners
\rput[tl](-5,12){\psvectorian[width=3cm]{63}}
\rput[tr](5,12){\psvectorian[width=3cm,mirror]{63}}
\rput[bl](-5,-5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,flip]{63}}
\rput[br](5,-5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,flip,mirror]{63}}



% TITLE 
\swabfamily
\rput(0.05,4.00){\vstretch{1.25}{\mytitle{\swabfamily{\scalebox{2}{Gilded}}}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I add a metallic (gilded) effect to the gold title to have it stand out a little more? I would also like to be able, possibly, to do the same for the border ornaments.

Thank you.

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I just commented it out above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A TikZ version of some non described gilded effect. Compile twice with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTex.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in, vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament, tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.6cm]
\node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
\node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
\node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
\node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
\node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
\node (n) at (current page text area) {\swabfamily{\scalebox{6}{Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
\fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The word "Gilded" with gold effect and border]

[image: Animation of "Gilded" with gold and gray]

Comment: You can use `fading transform={shift={(current page.center)}}` as in `\fill[path fading=mytext, fit fading=false, ball color=gold, fading transform={shift={(current page.center)}}] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);` to shift the center of the fading to the center of the page. Using this, you can omit all those not-so-nice `\vspace*{\fill} \centering` and `baseline=-1em` things.

Comment: Thanks - corrected/improved

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Now, you need to link the animation with the movement of the device you are using to display it! That would be the ultimate =D